# interpret arrow keys in raw mode (posix)

Tags: c, posix

I'm trying to create a shell (nothing serious just messing around) and want to read the arrow keys in raw mode to avoid control characters being printed to the screen, and actually be able to use them to go back and edit a line before I hit enter. It's probably possible to do with termios but is there an easier way of doing this? Or is it perhaps easy to do with termios? It just seems like a rather large subject that has to be studied in full.

I'm reading in lines from stdin in a loop and call fork > execvp with an argument vector that I create from the input string.

Comment: Are you using the curses library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It's probably possible to do with termios but is there an easier way
>   of doing this

By far the easiest approach would be to use the [`readline`](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) library which offers everything and more than what you're mentioning. It should be fairly easy to make your shell behave like a full-blown bash (line editing, command history) with relative ease.

Comment: Thanks, I just looked it up and it seems to be doing exactly what I want.

Comment: @foo Look for "line editing", "readline movement commands", "searching for commands in the history".

Answer (score 1):

Unless you actually want to do it yourself, I'd recommend you the [GNU Readline Library](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) which does these things for you.